# Http response body has quote marks from Dart Aqueduct server

Tags: json, dart, httpresponse, aqueduct

When a response is returned from an Aqueduct controller like this

```
return Response.ok('hello');
```

the body of the response has quote marks around it:

```
"hello"
```

The same thing when I return a JSON string like this:

```
return Response.ok('{"token":"$token"}');
```

I get this:

```
"{\"token\":\"eyJhbG...soOFY8\"}"
```

which is messing up the JSON parsing on the client side.

Is there any way to not send the quote marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default ContentType of the response is JSON already. If you want to send plane text then you need to set the content type to plain text.

```
// import 'dart:io';

return Response.ok('hello')..contentType = ContentType.text;
```

The response body will be

```
hello
```

To send JSON, just send a Map rather than converting it to a string yourself:

```
return Response.ok({'token':token});
```

This will give a response body of

```
{"token":"eyJhbGc...vCxdE"}
```

#### See also

- [Encoding Response Body Objects](https://aqueduct.io/docs/http/request_and_response/#encoding-response-body-objects)

#### Credit

Thank you to [Joe Conway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2535095/joe-conway) on the [Aqueduct Slack channel](http://slackaqueductsignup.herokuapp.com/) for help solving this problem. I am adding the solution here as a Q&A so others can find it easier.